# Controlar aplicativo java por fora

Tags: java, swing

Criei uma aplicação java SE que roda em background, sem swing nem nada... Mas como faço para controlar essa aplicação? por exemplo, em aplicativos python podemos executar comandos (python algo.py -c comando1 -u comando2), assim posso ter um controle sobre a aplicação, como eu faria isso com minha aplicação java?

E tem como eu controlar a aplicação por meio de outra aplicação java? Por exemplo: um painel feito com swing com as opções de pausar a thread da aplicação controlada, continuar, alterar informações de configuração, etc.

A aplicação será executada somente em Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uma solução para seu caso pode ser a utilização da classe ServerSocket. Na sua aplicação background você pode deixar como um servidor escutando uma porta em específico. E em outra aplicação você pode mandar comandos através do socket, com isso você pode manipular a sua aplicação server sabendo apenas o IP e porta;

## Lado Server

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  

public class Server {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        ServerSocket serv=null;  // Declara o socket 
        Socket s= null; // Socket de comunicação  

        BufferedReader entrada=null; //Leitor para a entrada de dados  

        try{  
            //Cria o ServerSocket na porta 9000   
            serv = new ServerSocket(9000);  
            //Aguarda uma conexão na porta especificada e cria   
            s = serv.accept();  
            //Cria um BufferedReader para o canal da stream de entrada de dados do socket  
            entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));  

            //Aguarda por algum dado e imprime a linha recebida quando recebe  
            System.out.println(entrada.readLine());      

        }catch(IOException e){  
            System.out.println("Falha ao criar socket.");  
        }finally{  
            try{  
                //Encerra o socket  
                s.close();  
                //Encerra o ServerSocket  
                serv.close();  
            }catch(IOException e){  
            
            }  
        }  

}
```

}

## Lado Client

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintStream;  
import java.net.Socket;  

public class Client {  

public static void main(String[] args){           
    Socket mSocket = null;  
    PrintStream mPrintStream = null;  

    try{  

    int x = 20;  
    mSocket = new Socket("<_ENDEREÇO_IP_>",9000);  
    mPrintStream = new PrintStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());  
    mPrintStream.println(x);  
    
    }catch(IOException e){                
    System.out.println("Falha ao enviar dados." + e.getMessage());  

    }finally{  
        try{  
            //Fecha o socket  
            mSocket.close();  
        }catch(IOException e){}  

    }  
}  
}
```

Comment: Não há outro meio, sem uso de rede?

Comment: Você pode utilizar socket server/client na mesma máquina, usando o ip de loopback 127.0.0.1

Comment: No momento não me vem nada a cabeça